# VBA code to change row color when value in column A changes

Tags: colors, excel, row, vba

My spreadsheet is set up like this:

I have a list of job numbers in column A and a corresponding list of Job titles in Column B. I need for all of the rows of a certain job number to be colored. e.g., rows 2-4 have "3705" in column A, so those rows would be colored red. Rows 5 & 6 have 4169 in column A and would be colored green. Rows 7-10 have 5518 in column A and would be colored red (alternate between red and green).

Can someone give me a VBA code that will do what I described above automatically/using a macro?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub colorize()

Dim r As Long, val As Long, c As Long

    r = 1
    val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
    c = 4 '4 is green, 3 is red '

    For r = 1 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value) Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value <> val Then
            If c = 3 Then
                c = 4
            Else
                c = 3
            End If
        End If

        ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .ColorIndex = c
            .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With

        val = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Add the following to the relevant Worksheet's module if you want the macro to fire every time a cell in column A changes value:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    colorize

End Sub
```

Comment: When using DIM you have to specify the variable type for each variable. The way you have it will only set c as integer. Both r and val will be of type variant. You can check this using VarType in VBA.

Comment: Vicky, when I try to run the top code you gave me (the long one) it says "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" Is that because of what Remnant was talking about? and if so how do I fix it? Also, when I tried to run the second code you gave me (the short one) it doesn't come up as an option to run (instead it shows a few other macros I have recorded). Sorry, I am new to VBA code etc; .. Thanks so much for your help (Remnant & Vicky)!

Comment: Hi @Colton, @Remnant edited my post to correct the "Dim" statements so if you are using it as it appears in the answer it will be fine. Your run-time error is probably related to the ActiveSheet thing - you need to have the relevant worksheet selected (i.e. as the active sheet), not the code module sheet, when you run it. I'm not sure about the second short snippet as that was provided by @Mike Woodhouse, but I think it is supposed to run automatically when anything changes in column A, so you woulnd't need to run it as a macro.

Comment: That makes more sense now, but I'm still doing something wrong. here's what I'm doing: I open the relevant workbook and nothing else (the workbook only has one sheet.) I open VBE (alt+F11) and in the project window right click on the relevant worksheet and choose insert Module. I then open that module and copy and paste the code you and remnant gave me (in the answer above) into the module code area. Then I hit run and get the error I mentioned before. I also tried pasting the code into the worksheet's code window, but that didn't work either. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? sorry..

Comment: Yes, paste the code into the module code error as discussed. Then go back to the worksheet itself and through the menus select Tools > Macro > Run, then select Colorize and click Run. If you just hit run from within the code editor then the code editor is the active sheet.

Comment: Okay, great- I see what you're saying. Also my first two rows did not contain values and that was messing it up. Now it is working great. Any way to change the colors it uses though? I'd prefer something not so bright- any light colors would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using only Excel formulas and conditional formatting if you can add a column.  You might not be able to alternate red/green, but only a color and no color.

[Alternate Excel Row Color Based on Content](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ContentBanding.aspx)